# Updating specific columns in a datagrid specified from a dropdown

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

Im New to ASP.NET and VB:NET so im at a quit low Level now.
Im trying to display a gridview using `<asp:BoundField DataField..>` or `<asp:TemplateField..>`.
When using Boundfield, I am able to get the viewgrid to display what i want, but im not able to edit it. it tells me: "Input string was not in a correct format". When using Templates i have trouble even displaying the gridview.

If possible to use the gridview i get to work and be able to edit that one,, then I will stick to this format.

My DB looks like this:

```
[TBL_CASE](
    [caseId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [caseSub] [int] NULL,
    [caseUser] [int] NULL,
    [caseType] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [caseRegBy] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [caseTopic] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [caseDesc] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [caseDtCreated] [datetime] NULL,
    [caseStatus] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

My GridView like this, With a data source below to fetch the drop down that I use to sort out what is displayed:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="caseList" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="editCase_RowEditing"
                OnRowUpdating="UpdateCase_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="updateCase_RowCancelingEdit">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="caseId" HeaderText="Saksnr" ItemStyle-Width="20" DataFormatString="Int" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="userName" HeaderText="Bruker" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="caseType" HeaderText="Type" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="caseRegby" HeaderText="Reg. av" ItemStyle-Width="60" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="caseTopic" HeaderText="Tittel" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="caseDesc" HeaderText="Beskrivelse" ItemStyle-Width="300" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="caseDtCreated" HeaderText="Opprettet dato" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="caseStatus" ItemStyle-Width="30">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#IIf(Boolean.Parse(Eval("caseStatus").ToString()),
 "Lukket", "Åpen")%></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

the update procedure im trying to use is the following:

```
Protected Sub UpdateCase_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)

    sqlConnection.Open()
    sqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("update TBL_CASE set TBL_CASE.caseType = @caseType, TBL_CASE.caseRegBy = @caseRegby, TBL_CASE.caseTopic = @caseTopic, TBL_CASE.caseDesc = @caseDesc where caseId = @caseID ")
    sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection

    Dim Id As Integer = caseList.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text
    Dim Type As String = DirectCast(caseList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("caseType"), TextBox).Text
    Dim Regby As String = DirectCast(caseList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("caseRegby"), TextBox).Text
    Dim Topic As String = DirectCast(caseList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("caseTopic"), TextBox).Text
    Dim Desc As String = DirectCast(caseList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("caseDesc"), TextBox).Text

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@caseID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Id
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@caseType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = Type
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@caseRegby", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Regby
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@caseTopic", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = Topic
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@caseDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 800).Value = Desc

    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    caseList.EditIndex = -1
    sqlConnection.Close()
    BindData()

End Sub
```

I don't understand what I have been written wrong. I see that if I use Template Fields, I have actually been able to update the DB, but then have a problem showing the SQL data into the grid view.

My error message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.caseType 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
```

request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.caseType
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.caseType]
Supportomatic_2000.Showcase.UpdateCase_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) +1031
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowUpdating(GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) +139
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +808
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +855
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +95
System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +121
System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +169System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

To the end i see that since I am using the tag:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="caseType" HeaderText="Type" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
```

I cannot use the fetch Method:

```
Dim Type As String = DirectCast(caseList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("caseType"), TextBox).Text
```

But needs to do it another way, is this correct? If yes, then how?

Comment: What error you are having? Exception message and stack trace would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out of my problem, and it seems like, when i changed the tag for the Fields I wanted to update from boundfield to template Field, it was working OK like the tags below:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Henv. gjelder">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="caseType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("caseType")%>'/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcaseType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("caseType")%>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtftrcaseType" runat="server"/>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvcaseType" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtftrcaseType" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validation"/>
                </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Templatefield>
```